# Symfony Doctrine entity manager and repository

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, repository-pattern, symfony, repository-design

I understand the benefit or repository pattern but I just can't understand in Symfony3 Doctrine there are `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` and `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`

1. What are the difference between the two?
2. Is repository should be injected to controller or entity manager?

   **Edit**
   The correct question should be: What's the proper way to access a repository from a controller?

   - Should a repository be injected to a controller as a service?
   - Should a repository be injected to another service as a service?
3. Should entity manager contain any query at all?
   **Edit**
   The correct question should be: should a service contain a query at all? Which @MateuszSip already explained, it could be done by injecting Entity Manager
4. Should a custom function like `getAvailableManagers` be put in
   repository or services? (Where `manager` is a repository and there
   are some logic in determining `available manager`)
5. How about a more generic function like `findAllManager`, should it be in repository or entity manager?

Currently I'm using Symfony3. Thank you very much

Cheers,

**Edit**
Talking to @MateuszSip (thanks mate), I decided to make my question clearer with an example below. Please note that below code are not representing real problem

controller

```
Class ManagementController
{
    public function assignManager($projectType)
    {
        // Grabbing a service
        $s = $this->get('mycompany_management_management_service')

        $managers = $s->findAvailableManagers();
        $managers = $s->checkCapability($managers, $projectType);

        return $managers
    }
}
```

repository

```
class ManagerRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findAvailableManagers() 
    {
        ...
        return $managers
    }

    public function checkCapability($managers, $type)
    {
        ...
        return $capableManagers
    }
}
```

services

```
class ManagementService 
{
   ... I am not sure what should be here.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. EntityManager is used to manage doctrine-related objects, so:

   - you can persist an entity object (it's now managed by doctrine, and ready to save)
   - you can remove an entity object (so it'll be deleted later)
   - you can flush, and it'll trigger pending operations
   - you can get a repository (to get objects you'll need) or use a generic api to get an object by a primary key
     etc.

It's a class that manages a state of objects and their relation to the database.

Repository is a pattern that standarizes an access to the entites.

2. If your app is complex, you should inject a separate service(s) to your controller. So there's a UserSaver service (as an example) that use entityManager to create/update a user and UserFinder (or something well-named) using UserRepository which's responsible of fetching user by defined criterias.
3. You can create a query using entity manager, but em itself cannot contain queries.
4. In my opinion, define a method inside a service, and a corresponding method in your UserRepository. At this moment, all of what you want should be fetched by a database, but it can change later.
5. In repository. Methods like: findByRole(role=manager), findIsActive, findOneBySecurityNumber relies to a repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For your point 4. How can the service access repository? Is it through injection? or is it through `->entityManager->getRepository` ?

Comment: You can define your repository as a service and inject it into your service.

Comment: If I define my repository as a service, why do I need of injecting it into another service? Shouldn't I just inject the repository in the controller as a service instead? Also if I'm using injection, what's the point of `->entityManager->getRepository` then? Thanks and sorry if it's too many questions

Comment: You call a service that know how to get data, but controller shouldn't be aware of implementation.
It's all about separating business logic from data source.

Comment: I agree that the controller shouldn't be aware of the implementation. That's why we have service. The one that I don't understand is ... why can't we use repository as a service that is used by controller directly ? Why there should be another service in between? Thanks again. You've been really helpful